# What are Istio alternative for Authentication Policy and what is Istio flow for development?

Tags: microservices, istio

At this url you can have a look at my project jut to have some context:
https://github.com/Deviad/clarity/tree/feature/hyperledger
Long story short I am building an open source framework for building Escrows that can take advantage of the latest PSD2 https://www.openbankingtracker.com/ 
It support Cryptocurrency payments and implements some sort of side chain in order to have a proof that a contract was signed.

Basically of all of the things that Istio does what I really need is the Authentication Policy using JWT.
This in order to avoid writing this part in every microservice that I am creating.
Of course the gateway is also something important.
The main issue is that I have no idea while I am developing using my IDE (Intellij IDEA) what I can do in order to avoid having to stop, rebuild and start containers every single time I need to rebuild since once I use Istio, I will need to use Istio also in development, otherwise I would have to write some dummy services that fake the authorization from istio when I want to check if a certain user has the permissions to access a resource.
What possibilities I have to have a lean workflow with Istio and eventually what alternatives to Istio do I have?

Answer (score 0):

As for the workflow part of my question, I have found a possible solution:
https://garden.io
There is a nice workshop available here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xfi9XqcZ76M